# Cannot use "root" name for items in multi-Project vsTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I've created a multi-project template.
I can create the projects OK with the name I want.
However for the items within the project they always get the full name of the project during the variable replacement while I want to use only the root part of the project name.

My solution vstemplate is as such:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>My Template</Name>
    <Description>Solution template</Description>
    <Icon>Icon.png</Icon>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.DataModel">
        APP.DataModel\ProjectTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

and the project template is:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>DataModel</Name>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="$saferootprojectname$.DataModel.csproj" File="APP.DataModel.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$.cs">MyClass.cs</ProjectItem>
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

When running the template entering "foo" in the wizard, I get a "foo.DataModel" project as expected.
In the "foo.DataModel" project however the file "MyClass.cs" is renamed to "foo.DataModel.cs" and not "foo.cs" as I want it to be.

I tried the different available variables and it didn't work.
I tried to use a custom parameter and that didn't work either.
I even created a wizard to add my own variable but it's either not picking up the replacement value if I don't use it anywhere else (and the template fails), or gives me the same result of "foo.DataModel" if I use the replacement variable in the project name.

I had a similar issue with my item template but I could use $fileinputname$ and $safeitemname$ to get it to work.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get what I want.

I created an IWizard and overwrote the `$safeprojectname$` for each project like this:

```
 private static string basename;

 public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
        {
            if (runKind == WizardRunKind.AsMultiProject)
            {
                basename = replacementsDictionary["$specifiedsolutionname$"];
            }
            else
            {
                replacementsDictionary["$safeprojectname$"] = basename;
            }
        }
```

Then I added a reference to the wizard (that must be GAc-ed) to every template (the solution and every project template).

The solution template:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>My Template</Name>
    <Description>Solution template</Description>
    <Icon>Icon.png</Icon>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.DataModel">
        APP.DataModel\ProjectTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
  <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>Wizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=97aaf9683a0dbe2b</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>Wizard.Wizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
</VSTemplate>
```

The project template:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>DataModel</Name>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="$saferootprojectname$.DataModel.csproj" File="APP.DataModel.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$safeprojectname$.cs">MyClass.cs</ProjectItem>
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
  <WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>Wizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=97aaf9683a0dbe2b</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>Wizard.Wizard</FullClassName>
  </WizardExtension>
</VSTemplate>
```

Now everything works as I want it to.

I spent way too much time figuring this out so I hope it helps someone out there.